# DAX Excluding Assets Out of Contract Date

Tags: azure, powerbi, dax

I am trying to create a measure that will sum invoices totals for all assets but exclude assets whose contracts have expired. The tables look something like this:

Service Data:

```
Invoice Amount
Asset Key
Invoice Date
```

Asset Data:

```
Asset Key 
Contract Start Date
Contract End Date
```

I am also using a date table that is attached to a slicer on the main page of my dashboard. I would like to be able to select a date range on the slicer and have it limit which assets' invoices in includes in the total in respect to the date range selected on the slicer.

Here is what I was attempting so far:

```
NewISA = 
    var enddate = MIN(F_Service_Invoice_Summary[Invoice_Date])
    Return
    IF(
        enddate <= F_Asset[End_Date], 
        SUM(F_Service_Invoice_Summary[Invoice_Segment_Amount]), 
        0)
```

Comment: did your attempt work? what was the result?

Comment: The result was:
 A single value for column 'End_Date' in table 'F_Asset' cannot be determined. This can happen when a measure formula refers to a column that contains many values without specifying an aggregation such as min, max, count, or sum to get a single result. I received this error message:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a relationship between the ServiceData and AssetData on the AssetKey field and that you have a relationship between your DateTable and ServiceData table on the InvoiceDate field, the following formula should work:

```
 Total Invoiced Active Contracts =
 CALCULATE (
     SUM ( ServiceData[Invoice Amount] ),
     FILTER (
         AssetData,
         AssetData[Contract Start Date] <= MIN ( DateTable[Date] )
             && AssetData[Contract EndDate] > MAX ( DateTable[Date] )
     )
 )
```

We can use MIN(datetable[date]) and MAX(datetable[date]) to determine the interval that is filtered in the datetable to only select contracts that are active during the whole period. Please keep in mind that if you do not select an interval, the formula will only return contracts that started before the first date in your datetable and end after the last date in your datetable.